# Import new library - Angular 5

Tags: angular, import

I want to know how to get the details of a library before than getting imported. 
I explain it better:

For example:

To import all the libraries in my project, I use `app.module.ts`.

This is one **example**:

1) *import*

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

2) *imports*

```
imports: [routes, { useHash: true })]
```

My question is the following:

I would like to know where should I get the information needed to import them. In this case I do not need to use an import, because it is not a component, but I would like to know how should I call it to import it to my `NgModule` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-formatter))

How should I use? Which name should I take? Where do I take it?

Comment: You seem to be confusing two different kinds of imports. Also it's not clear to me what your question is. But in general, to find out how to use things: read their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st import you mention is **Typescript** import. If you skipped this import Typescript would complain in your module definition that it doesnt know RouteModule. Example:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

The 2nd import is used to import other **Angular modules**. Example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Therefore if you want to use `xml-formatter` which is NOT Angular module but plain javascript library you don't have to import it in `app.module.ts`.

Instead its a good practice to wrap it in a service and in such service you will import just the library itself:

```
import xmlFormatter from 'xml-formatter';

class XmlFormatterService {
  format(input) {
    return xmlFormatter();
  }
}
```

Later use the service in the component:

```
class AppComponent {
  constructor(xmlFormatterService: XmlFormatterService) {
    console.log(xmlFormatterService.format('<root></root>'));
  }
}
```

For better understanding Angular Modules checkout documentation: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules